# Remove Duplicated Values From Array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

**What I want to achieve**

I want to make as many arrays as the number of the secondArray (in this particular case: 2) only if the value is 1 
**I have the array firstArray**.

```
firstArray
(
    [analysis] => coding
    [data] => Array
        (
            [data1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => "test"
                        )

                )

            [data2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [age] => 22
                        )

                )

            [data3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [CODE] => 1111 //Stable
                            [QUANTITY] => 1
                        )
                )

        )

)
```

**My second array is secondArray**

```
secondArray
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [test1] => 1
            [test2] => 1
            [test3] => 1
            [test4] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [test1] => 1
            [test2] => 
            [test3] => 1
            [test4] => 
        )

)
```

**What I want to achieve**

I want to make as many arrays as the number of the secondArray (in this particular case: 2) only if the value is 1
**The result must be:**

```
    firstArray
    (
        [analysis] => coding
        [data] => Array
            (
                [data1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => "test"
                            )
    
                    )
    
                [data2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [age] => 22
                            )
    
                    )
    
                [data3] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [CODE] => 1111 //Stable
                                [QUANTITY] => 1
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [CODE] => 0001
                                [QUANTITY] => 1
                            )
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [CODE] => 0002
                                [QUANTITY] => 1
                            )
                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [CODE] => 0003
                                [QUANTITY] => 1
                            )
                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [CODE] => 0004
                                [QUANTITY] => 1
                            )
                    )
    
            )
    
    )
```

**and second firstArray must be**

```
firstArray
    (
        [analysis] => coding
        [data] => Array
        (
            [data1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => "test"
                        )

                )

            [data2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [age] => 22
                        )

                )

            [data3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [CODE] => 1111 //Stable
                            [QUANTITY] => 1
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [CODE] => 0001
                            [QUANTITY] => 1
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [CODE] => 0003
                            [QUANTITY] => 1
                        )
                )

        )

)
```

**the code I am currently working on is, but I do not get the desired result. the second firstArray also prints the values of the first firstArray**

```
foreach ($secondArray as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'test1' && $value == "1"){
        array_push($firstArray ['data']['data3'],
            array('CODE' =>  "0001",
                'QUANTITY' => "1"
            )
        );
    }
    if($key == 'test2' && $value == "1"){
        array_push($firstArray ['data']['data3'],
            array('CODE' =>  "0002",
                'QUANTITY' => "1"
            )
        );
    }
    if($key == 'test3' && $value == "1"){
        array_push($firstArray ['data']['data3'],
            array('CODE' =>  "0003",
                'QUANTITY' => "1"
            )
        );
    }
    if($key == 'test4' && $value == "1"){
        array_push($firstArray ['data']['data3'],
            array('CODE' =>  "0004",
                'QUANTITY' => "1"
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write for example a nested foreach and check if the key starts with `test` instead of hardcoding all the different keys.

Then increment a variable for the value of `CODE` and use for example a padding for the leading zeroes.

```
$firstArray = [
    "analysis" => "coding",
    "data" => ["data1" => [["name" => "test"]], "data2" => [["age" => 22]], "data3" => [["CODE" => 1111, "QUANTITY" => 1]]]
];

$secondArray = [
    ["test1" => "1", "test2" => "1", "test3" => "1", "test4" => "1"],
    ["test1" => "1", "test2" => "", "test3" => "1", "test4" => ""]
];

$result = [];

foreach ($secondArray as $sa) {
    $code = 1;
    $tmp = $firstArray;
    foreach ($sa as $key => $value) {
        if (substr($key, 0, 4) === "test" && $value === "1") {
            $tmp["data"]["data3"][] = [
                "CODE" => str_pad($code, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT),
                "QUANTITY" => 1
            ];
        }
        $code++;
    }
    $result[] = $tmp;
}

foreach ($result as $r) {
    print_r($r);
}
```

Instead of *substr* to check the first 4 characters to start with *test* you could also make the check more specific and check for *test* followed by 1 o more digits using:

```
if (preg_match("/^test\d+$/", $key) && $value === "1") {
```

See a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/T3YUK).

Output

```
Array
(
    [analysis] => coding
    [data] => Array
        (
            [data1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => test
                        )

                )

            [data2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [age] => 22
                        )

                )

            [data3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [CODE] => 1111
                            [QUANTITY] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [CODE] => 0001
                            [QUANTITY] => 1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [CODE] => 0002
                            [QUANTITY] => 1
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [CODE] => 0003
                            [QUANTITY] => 1
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [CODE] => 0004
                            [QUANTITY] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [analysis] => coding
    [data] => Array
        (
            [data1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => test
                        )

                )

            [data2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [age] => 22
                        )

                )

            [data3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [CODE] => 1111
                            [QUANTITY] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [CODE] => 0001
                            [QUANTITY] => 1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [CODE] => 0003
                            [QUANTITY] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```